# How can I write really long arrays in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I need to write an array that can hold 2^(N/2) elements. N can be as large as 2^62 which is around ~2 billion elements. Is there a way I could store all these elements without giving Java more memory? I am using this list of strings to search for collisions / find duplicates.

**EDIT**

I am trying to perform a Birthday Hash Attack on a portion of Sha-1. N can be as large as 2^62. In order to perform a Birthday Attack I need to generate 2^(N/2) random Strings of a set length.

**EDIT EDIT**

This is for a Cryptography Assignment.

Comment: 2^2bn is a lot more than you think... Did you mean n can be 31, which makes 2^n=2bn?

Comment: Java will not be able to hold an array of this size even if the arrays were holding bytes

Comment: 2^(10^9) ~ 10^(a 3 and then 100,000,000 zeroes) .. Is the *universe* large enough?

Comment: Use a HashSet to hold the Strings. It doesn't allow duplicates. If you try to add(yourString) it'll return true if it's not in the set, false if it is already there. The HashSet can grow to accommodate more elements.

Comment: Tell us what do you try to do. You probably don't need to make such a big array.

Comment: Most JVMs will have a limit somewhere between 16MB and 2GB for the size of a single object.  And, of course, the size of overall heap storage is apt to be limited to anywhere from 2GB to 500GB, by both architectural limitations and available physical resources.

Comment: Keep in mind that simply initializing a >2GB object and loading it with your data will take a substantial amount of time.  You're almost certainly better off using some sort of database.

Comment: @Jongware [Its not at all](http://www.universetoday.com/36302/atoms-in-the-universe/), even if you somehow managed to store 1 byte in each atom...

Comment: @assylias Looks like i caused some confusion.. The array I need to hold is of size 2^31 which is ~2 billion elements.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for a [sparse array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_array) implementation in Java.

Comment: I'm curious where the worst case of 2 billion is coming from, considering what you're using it for.

Comment: @Jesper All of the elements are randomly generated strings. A sparse array is interesting, but I am trying to search for equal two elements  in a array list that has a >50% chance of having two elements being the same hash/string.

Comment: @MxyL I am looking for a Hash collision by using a Birthday Attack. I need to randomly generate 2^(N/2) array combinations where 2^N = the total number of possible Hash combinations.

Comment: If any 2 elements have a 50% chance of having the same hash, you're not using an appropriate hash.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this. I've just tried the following exercise:

Here is my code:

```
public class TestBigArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] a = new String[2*1_000_000_000];
    }
}
```

I tried to run it with default heap and got excpetion:

```
c:\temp>java TestBigArray
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at TestBigArray.main(TestBigArray.java:3)
```

Then I increased the heap up to 20G and the program worked:

```
c:\temp>java -Xmx20G TestBigArray

c:\temp>
```

But it took a minute to start on my laptop and Windows was almost stuck during this time.

So, I do not recommend you do do such thing in practice unless you really need this and you have very strong machine to run on. I'd suggest you to use collections (e.g. list), specially `LinkedList`.

Comment: You have 20GB+ on your laptop? Nice! ;-)

Comment: Lol not sure my computer can handle a 20GB heap. I was looking for a way of doing this without increasing the heap space.